# Ajax based search output drop down coming behind the video

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html5-video

Here http://strutmymutt.com/development/rescuetraining/new-owners-guide, search outout is coming behind the video. I already put wmode=transparent for the video.

Please check this http://screencast.com/t/PU99Zv2OHqXR for exact working.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your div.searchForm has **`overflow:hidden`**

I removed that property in **chrome** and i could see the list above the video

Answer (score 0):

give the search a css of `z-index: 99999;` and the video a css of `z-index: 1`

Comment: z-index wont help because of the overflow:hidden